# Search is showing questions for tags that have been re-tagged more than 24 hours ago

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

I have been removing the [node] tag when it appears to be used to say "Node.JS" and there is already a [node.js] tag on the question. I have been using [the search [node] "Node.JS"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bnode%5d%20%22node.js%22) and generally reviewing each question after setting the word "node" highlighted with my browser search.

You will see all my edits brought to the top under the Active tag. The thing is, they are not going away from the search results no matter which tab I choose. Even the least recent of my edits (near the bottom of the first page) is more than 24 hours old. Why does it not go away from the list?

Comment: Are you sure it's more than 24 hours?

Comment: @random 20:28 of the 28th versus right now is 21:36 of the 29th, on one of the much later ones.

Comment: Wonder if the other search term is forcing a latency

Comment: @Grace: I don't follow at all what you are saying, but yes. [My least recent edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050279/require-a-node-js-module) is more than 24 hours older than [my most recent edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140661/global-variables-for-node-js-standard-modules). I am looking at the mouseover text which shows a UTC timestamp.

Comment: There's a greater than 24 hour difference between the two timestamps I provided, George. I was merely reinforcing your point.

Comment: @Grace: Sorry, I did not understand your comment, but now I get it. *20:28 of the 28th* [of March] *versus right now is 21:36 of the 29th*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in an optimization we made to how we index answers on updated questions, what you're seeing in results are *answers* that roll up to questions...answers that weren't properly re-indexed after the tags on their parent (the question) changed.

I've just deployed a fix for this, but that won't magically fix it, we'll run a full re-index of all posts on all sites in the next hour to update all history, and the query fix resolves this going forward.  I'll update this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) once the re-indexing process is complete.